# Implementing If-Match HTTP header in Express.JS

Tags: node.js, express, http, http-headers

Context: I am trying to prevent data overwriting due to concurrent updates by multiple users on the same database entity.

Question: How can I implement `If-Match` HTTP header in POST calls to respond with HTTP status 412 (Precondition Failed) when the DB has already been modified by another user?

My intended approach: 
When a POST call is made to `POST /user/123`, I want to compare the `ETag` available in `If-Match` header of the POST call with the `ETag` present in the response header of the endpoint `GET /user/123`. To accomplish this, I have to invoke the GET route from the POST route, to extract the ETag. Is this even possible?

Comment: Did you end up finding a solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke GET from the POST route using **res.redirect('/getroutename')**

This way you can compare the ETag received from the get call, and achieve your intended approach.

Comment: res.redirect will not let me compare the ETag in my node service